# password_verify gives false after password_hash, should be true

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords, password-encryption

I keep getting the wrong result with this and can't understand why.

I store the new user and his password like this:

```
// get password input
$pass = $_POST[ 'password' ];

$options = [
    'cost' => 12
];

$pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
// add to db

$sql = "insert into clients(first_name, last_name, email, password_hash) values ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass')";
```

for password '**123456**' I get this:
**$2y$12$DUd9LWGk2b26r2nQZ6KsfexFrHI/36RJrq8lAo8vk6XC6VKibIPVG**

Next step verify password:

```
// get password input
$pass = $_POST[ 'password' ];

// get row hash from database 
$sql = "select email, password_hash, active from clients where email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows( $result ) == 0)
{
    // Email not found in the database... 
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// true if password is correct
if ( password_verify( $pass, $row['password_hash'] ) ) 
{
    // logged in
}
else 
{
    $passInDb = $row['password_hash'];
    // Login failed
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Incorrect email or password. Cannot verify: $pass ,\n $passInDb" ;
    // redirect to login page
    header('Location: ../index.php');   
}
```

Now when I try to log in I get:

Incorrect email or password. Cannot verify: **123456** , **$2y$12$DUd9LWGk2b26r2nQZ6KsfexFrHI/36RJrq8lAo8vk6XC6VKibIPVG**

I really don't understand why the password_verify gives me false...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: You don't seem to be substituting the values. Wouldn't you need to use .$VALUE. insead of just $VALUE? But you, *seriously, not kidding around here*, should be using prepared statements like PDO. You're in for a world of hurt if you don't.

Comment: You've got nothing in the if when verify is true. Shouldn't you be clearing `$_SESSION['error']` there, maybe setting `$_SESSION['username']`, and redirecting somewhere?

Comment: In other words, is `password_verify` really returning false or does it just seem that way due to something missing.  You could also have a browser caching issue if you didn't set no-cache headers on this page.